# Semicolon error in the trigger

Tags: trigger

```
 trigger DuplicatePlanName on Plan_rles__c (before insert) {

   //Get all plan name related to the incoming planrecords in a single SOQL query.
   Plan_rles__c[] planslist = System.Trigger.new;
   Set plannameset = new Set();
   for(Plan_rles__c s : planslist{
    plannameset.add(s.name);
   }

   //Get list of duplicate Plan Names
   List duplicateplanlist = [Select s.Name From Plan_rles__c s
    where s.name IN :plannameset];

         Set duplicatenames = new Set();

      for(Plan_rles__c s : duplicateplanlist){
        duplicatenames.add(s.name);
      }

    for(Plan_rles__c s : planslist){
        if(duplicatenames.contains(s.name)){
            s.name.addError('Record already exist with same Plan name');
        }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing correct syntax for [Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) in apex

Assuming the datatype of the collection you need is String ,the syntax will look like below

```
   Set<String> plannameset = new Set<String>();
```

Similarly for the other set as well

```
 Set<String> duplicatenames = new Set<String>;
```